# Is there any problem with including Latitude and Longitude as separate covariates?

Tags: modeling, spatial, circular-statistics

In a model, is there any issue with including two covariates (Longitude and Latitude) in order to measure the effect of "position" on the outcome variables?

The reason I am unsure of this approach is that we are using two separate covariates that really represent one general covariate called "position", and I am wondering whether the model will manage to capture that?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that latitude and longitude represent points on the surface of an approximately spherical manifold (i.e. the surface of the earth). This is different than operating in a Euclidean space as many models assume. For example, longitudes -179.9deg and +179.9deg are close, even though the coordinates themselves have a large difference. Your model should take this into account if you're looking at points distributed widely across the globe, or in a region that spans where the coordinates 'wrap around'.

Comment: In *all* regression models (and most other models, too), data are reduced to vectors of $k$ real numbers: that is, "positions" in $k$ dimensions.  If your argument were correct, then all regression models would include just "one general covariate"!

Answer (score -1):

Separate them.  At the end of the day 'position' sounds like a two dimensional object, so if your model is n-dimensional you have no problem.  As long as the two dimensions of your position are not perfectly correlated you should be ok with linear models.  If they are perfectly correlated, then the model will need to drop one since there would be no information gained including both relative to including just one.